# Git terminal output

Tags: git

I added a few files to my git repo. I then added a directory and moved them into there. I then added the directory using `git add`

What does this mean tell me?

```
On branch master

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   newDir/TMXParser.c
new file:   newDir/Tilemap.c
new file:   newDir/test.xml
new file:   newDir/tileImage2.png
new file:   TMXParser.c
new file:   Tilemap.c
new file:   test.xml
new file:   tileImage2.png

Changed but not updated:
 (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

deleted:    TMXParser.c
deleted:    Tilemap.c
deleted:    test.xml
deleted:    tileImage2.png

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.DS_Store
```

Are the files being added twice if I commit? How do I remove this .DS_Store from terminal?

Comment: Did you move the files using `git mv` or just `mv`?  I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: I just dragged them into the folder. So it looks like it must all be done by the terminal. In the above. are the new files and the deleted files going to cancel each other or what is this message saying

Comment: see [jleedev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506421/git-terminal-output/5506472#5506472) below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way would have been to use `git mv` to move the files into the directory; as it stands you can simply `git rm` them. You have told git that you wish to *copy* the files into the subdirectory. Once you `git rm` them, the output of `git status` will tell you that git wants to *move* the files into the subdirectory.

A shortcut is `git add -u`, which informs git of files which have been modified or removed. It will not add new files, though. If you rename files, the easiest way to inform git is with `git add -A`, which looks at modified, removed, and untracked files. It will remove your four removed files and add the .DS_Store file.

The best way to hide the `.DS_Store` file is to globally ignore it:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are being added once. In the newDir folder. What's getting deleted its git's reference to those files in the root.

To remove .DS_Store, create a file called .gitignore and put a line saying '.DS_Store' in there (without the quotes).

Probably you want to 'git add .' and that'll just add all your file changes, then 'git commit -m "My message"'

Answer (score 0):

This output tells you you have a bunch of new files that will be committed next time you do `git commit`, some in that newDir and also some in your top directory.

Then there are some files that were in your root directory that have been removed. You can do `git add -u` and then `git commit` to commit that change.

If you just moved those files without modifying them, you can do those two steps and git will figure out by itself that those files were moved.

And you have one file that git knows nothing about .DS_Store (you should probably add that into the .gitignore.